# take mic input from javascript and process the output with python, so I can deploy it on heroku

Tags: javascript, python, heroku

I created a coronavirus voice assistant program with python, using Flask module. I have a SpeechRecognition module as TTS and PyAudio module as for getting the mic input. It works on localhost, but when I tried deploying it on heroku, mic is not working because PyAudio only works on your local machine and not on remote server.

Is it possible to get mic input on clients browser and return it as string with variable on python, so I can easily process it on my python code.

Is there any other way on python I can use to make it work? What about using an STT API?
I do not know javascript well..

Here's the heroku site:
https://ncov-assistant.herokuapp.com/

Here's my repository: https://github.com/magbuhosjames/corvus_with_flask